# Choose elements from array randomly in matlab and store the remain element

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, random

I have array contain 1 column with 225 rows and I want to select 170 elements from these elements randomly and store it in another array also store the remain elements at another array, I used this code to choose randomly elements but I don't know how I can store the remain elements (55) at another array !

Code : my original array A

```
msize = numel(A);
firstpart = A(randperm(msize, 170))

secondpart = !!!!! ( remain elements ) % This is my question
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of throwing away the other elements, just get a permutation of *all* of them and *then* partition the array:

```
msize = numel(A);
allperm = A(randperm(msize));
firstpart = allperm(1:170);
secondpart = allperm(171:end);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean indexing.

```
A = rand(255,1); % just generating an example matrix
indices = false(size(A));
indices(randsample(1:numel(A),170)) = true; % select what to keep
firstpart = A(indices);
secondpart = A(~indices);
```

Comment: I like this idea, particularly if it's important to keep the elements in sorted order.

Comment: Haha, I liked (+1) your idea, it's very elegant : ) I've had situations before where having boolean indexing is useful for other reasons as well, but it depends a lot on what else will be going on in the code.

Comment: I will try this idea :)